# Magento 2: Adding Sample Data to an Already Installed System

Tags: magento2, composer, sample-data

Is it possible to add the sample data to an already running Magento 2 system?  Or is this only possible at install time?

If I run

```
php bin/magento sampledata:deploy
```

This will add the sample data modules to my `composer.json` file.  This installs the modules into my system.  However, it does not (seem to?) automatically deploy any of the products, users, etc.

Answer (score 4):

Looks like you are missing the:
php bin/magento setup:upgrade

Which would actually do the install of the sample data according to http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.0/install-gde/install/sample-data-after-composer.html